# How to access input id or placeholder ,anything that can get me to the search box -under multiple div , selenium java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

HTML

```
<div class="mob-search-box hidden-desk without-sticky">
    <form class="form minisearch" id="wizzySearchForm-Mobile" action="/pages/search" method="get" data-gtm-form-interact-id="0">
        <div class="wizzy-custom-search-form-wrapper mf-initial wizzy-custom-search-bar">
            <div class="wizzy-search-form-mobile-wrapper mf-initial"></div>
            <div class="wizzy-search-form mf-initial">
                <label for="search" style="display: none;"></label>
                <input id="wizzy-search-mobile-input-2" type="search" name="q" placeholder="Search for " class="input-text search-query" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" style="display: inline-block;" autofocus="" data-gtm-form-interact-field-id="0">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

i have tried the below line to execute

```java
WebElement searchbox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='mob-search-box hidden-desk without-sticky']//div[@class='wizzy-custom-search-form-wrapper mf-initial wizzy-custom-search-bar']//div[@class='wizzy-search-form mf-initial']//input[@id='wizzy-search-mobile-input-2']"));
```

Comment: What happens when that code runs? Do you get an error? If so, post the full error message as text, properly formatted. If not, describe what isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The INPUT you are searching for has an ID. You should always use that.

```
WebElement searchbox = driver.findElement(By.id("wizzy-search-mobile-input-2"));
```

If that isn't working, you need to check a few things:

1. See if the ID is unique on the page using the dev console. Press F12 to open the console and enter `$$("#wizzy-search-mobile-input-2")`. Does it return more than 1 element?
2. Make sure the element is visible. You might be looking at the wrong INPUT. Selenium can't interact with an invisible element. How would a user cause this element to become visible? Follow those steps in your script and then you can interact with it. Use the code below to wait for it to be visible,

   ```
   WebElement searchbox = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("wizzy-search-mobile-input-2")));
   ```
3. Make sure the element isn't in an IFRAME. If it is, you'll need to switch into the IFRAME context to access the INPUT.

Comment: WebElement form = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(30)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='wizzySearchForm-Mobile']")));

this worked for me finally

Comment: Don't use wait for presence. Presence just means that the element exists in the DOM, not that it can be interacted with. Instead wait for visible if you plan to get text from it, etc. Wait for clickable if you plan to click it. Using the right wait will prevent intermittent failures. Also, if you are using an ID to locate the element, use `By.id()` not `By.xpath()`. I've updated the code in my answer.